# Need to query and return an Object from a hashMap

Tags: spring, jpa

I have an entity in Spring which has primary key Timestamp and a HashMap of String, Double values.

My goal is to query using the Timestamp and return an Object with that Timestamp along with the map values.

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
@Query("select s from Measurement s join s.map m where ?1 in (VALUE(m))")
Measurement findByTimestamp(ZonedDateTime timestamp);
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="measurement")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Measurement {


@Id
@JsonProperty(value="timestamp") @NotNull
private ZonedDateTime timestamp;

@JsonAnySetter
@ElementCollection
private Map<String, Double> metrics = new HashMap<>();
@ElementCollection
private Map<String, Double> metricsView;

public ZonedDateTime getTimestamp() {
  return timestamp;
}

Repository
@Repository
public interface MeasurementRepository extends JpaRepository<Measurement, Long> {

@Query("select s from Measurement s join s.map m where ?1 in (VALUE(m))")
Measurement findByTimestamp(ZonedDateTime timestamp);
}
```

Expecting something like:

```
{
  "dewPoint": 17.1,
  "precipitation": 0,
  "temperature": 27.5,
  "timestamp": "2015-09-01T16:20:00.000Z"
}
```

Comment: Your map contains Doubles as values. How could the values (which are Doubles) contain a ZonedDateTime?

Comment: My Map doesn't have the ZonedDateTime, that's an independent field in my Measurements Object

Comment: I understood that, but apparently you didn't, since your query tries to find a ZonedDateTime (?1)  into the values of the map m, which is a Map<String, Double>.

Comment: I *think* that all you want is just findById().

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, that wasn't the case. My issue, I think lies in that fact that my Map is not properly joined such that when I query by Id, it will only return the timestamp when I want it to return the time stamp and all the metrics.